# Deploy nodejs with socket in GKE, auto restart after 30sec issue

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, socket.io, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed my nodejs server with socket.io in the Google Kubernetes engine. I used nodeport and externel https ingress. But the socket automatically restarts after 30sec. I identified the problem for ingress and I also set timeoutSec: 3600 and sessionAffinity: ClientIP. But the problem didn't solve.
There is any way to add SSL certificate without ingress or How can I fix this problem?

I change nodeport to Externel LoadBalancer its solved the problem but i can't add ssl certificate without ingress when i add ingress its like same issue.

### deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lyxa-backend-test
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: lyxa-backend-test
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: lyxa-backend-test
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 0
      maxUnavailable: 1
  replicas: 2 # number of pods
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lyxa-backend-test
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: lyxa-backend-test
          image: gcr.io/for-poc-325210/lyxa-backend-test:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5001
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: TZ
              value: Europe/Stockholm
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: dropimagepullkey
```

### service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: lyxa-backend-test-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/app-protocols: |
      {
        "https": "HTTPS",
        "http": "HTTP"
      }
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5001
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 5001
  selector:
    app: lyxa-backend-test
```

### backendConfig.yaml

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: lyxa-backend-test-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 2147483647
  sessionAffinity:
    affinityType: "CLIENT_IP"
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 3600
```

ingress.yaml

---

```
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "lyxa-backend-test-ingress"
  namespace: "default"
  annotations:
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "lyxa-backend-test-ssl-certificate"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce-internal"
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "lyxa-backend-test-backendconfig"}'
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: "lyxa-backend-test-service"
      port:
        number: 80
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you are using socket.io and trying to expose a WebSocket endpoint?

Comment: @GariSingh no. socket is working but ingress automatically triggers after 30sec that's why socket disconnected and connected after every 30sec

Comment: So you are setting https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#timeout ?   Can you post your deployment specs?

Comment: Yes, I set timeoutSec: 3600 but it's not working.

Comment: The `cloud.google.com/backend-config` annotation should be on the Service and not the Ingress.

Comment: How can I add ssl certificate

Comment: When I create ingress its occur same problem